# How to determine the type of an generic array element with reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

What I'm trying to do is without generic types is simple.

```
SomeType[] s = new SomeType[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5: i++){
  s[i]= new SomeType();
}
```

Using generics this is what I have so far.

```
private static T TypeMapper<T>(dynamic handle) {

    if (typeof(T).IsArray)
    {
        Type elementType = typeof(T).GetElementType();
        int arrayLength = handle.Length;
        Array array = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, arrayLength);

//???  How to get the type of an generic array element
        Type typeOfthis = typeof(array[0]).GetElementType();

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
        {
//??? How to create an instance from it.
            array[i] = new typeOfthis ();
        }


        T obj = (T)(object)array;
        return obj;
    }
    else
    {}
```

Then calling the TypeMapper function with.

```
dynamic t = new TextSpan[4];
var result = TypeMapper<TextSpan[]>(t)
```

How can I get the type of an generic array element.

```
Type typeOfthis = typeof(array[0]).GetElementType();//Not Working
```

And how to create an instance from it.

```
array[i] = new typeOfthis ();
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

**The Solution of Rubidium 37  was marked as correct**

```
Type typeofitem = array.GetType().GetElementType();
```

instead of

```
Type typeOfthis = typeof(array[0]).GetElementType();
```

and

```
array.SetValue(Activator.CreateInstance(typeofitem), i);
```

instead of

```
array[i] = new typeOfthis ();
```

Thanks also for the other solutions here, but they quite missing the point that I can pass `SomeType[]` or `SomeType` as T to `TypeMapper<T>(dynamic handle)`.
Then I can then derive from the type if it is an array or not and process the handle as needed.

**offtopic**
The long breath reason behind it is to marshal javascript types from v8 used by the v8dotnet wrapper which returns objects which have an equal behavior like dynamic objects.Instead of explaining what an `InternalHandle handle` is I reduced it to dynamic so that it is comprehensible.

Comment: Oh boy. Where to start. What are you actually trying to do? You've presented your (non-working) *solution*, but what is your *problem*? This really looks like a wrong solution to... well, pretty much any problem. Are you just looking for `return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => new T()).ToArray()`? I don't see any reason to use reflection here, anywhere. *Add your problem*.

Comment: `array[0]` return element so `array[0].GetType()` is enough to getting element type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have an array element, you have an object, that can be a different type from other array elements (like a derived type).
Then you can get the type of a single element array as you do for any standalone object.

You should replace

```
Type typeOfthis = typeof(array[0]).GetElementType();
```

with

```
Type typeOfthis = array[0].GetType();
```

Whereas, when you want create an object of any type, you can simply using Activator.CreateInstance or retrieve one ConstructorInfo from the Type.
Replace

```
array[i] = new typeOfthis ();
```

with

```
array[i] = Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfthis);
```

Just for you yo know..
- Remember that Activator.CreateInstance will try to call a parameterless constructor of the type you pass to it, then that type need to have such a constructor.
- The object you create need to be compatible with the array's Element type (assignable to it, like a derived class).
- If you know in advance that all elements of the array are (or should be) of the same type, then you don't need to get the type for each element; instead, typeof(T).GetElementType() should be enough.
- If the element type is a class and you don't need to assign concrete values because they are assigned later, or you know that the elementi type is struct, then you don't need to fill the array.

A part of that details, if you want to create a new array, given its length and the (concrete) type of its elements, you can try one of the following:

```
public static Array CreateAndFillArray(Type type, int length)
{
    var result = Array.CreateInstance(type, length);
    for (int ixItem = 0; ixItem < result.Length; ixItem++)
        result.SetValue(Activator.CreateInstance(type), ixItem);
    return result;
}
public static T[] CreateAndFillArray<T>(int length)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var result = new T[length];
    for (int ixItem = 0; ixItem < result.Length; ixItem++)
        result[ixItem] = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    return result;
}
public static T[] CreateAndFillArray<T>(int length)
    where T : new()
{
    var result = new T[length];
    for (int ixItem = 0; ixItem < result.Length; ixItem++)
        result[ixItem] = new T();
    return result;
}
```

Regards,
Daniele.

Comment: Best answer ever!!! But a small error. User **Type typeofitem = array.GetType().GetElementType();** instead of **Type typeOfthis = array[0].GetType();**

Comment: You're right: it is better to get the element type from the type of the array; in your sample you did it through " Type elementType = typeof(T).GetElementType();" and the third note of the solution was just relating to it. Obviously when the method receives T as the generic array type. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn something more about generics (and generalization in general). If you want to fill an array with default instances of a type, you can use this:

```
void ConstructAll<T>(T[] array) where T : new()
{
  for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
  {
    array[i] = new T();
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't really look like a good idea. What problem are you trying to solve? And why would you think using `dynamic` is a good solution?

Comment: and if you *can't* add the `where T : new()` constraint: `array[i] = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();` instead